# Casting the Dataframe columns with validation in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to cast the column of the data frame containing values as all string to a defined schema data types. 
While doing the casting we need to put the corrupt records (records which are of wrong data types) into a separate column

Example of Dataframe

```
+---+----------+-----+
|id |name      |class|
+---+----------+-----+
|1  |abc       |21   |
|2  |bca       |32   |
|3  |abab      | 4   |
|4  |baba      |5a   |
|5  |cccca     |     |
+---+----------+-----+
```

Json Schema of the file:

```
 {"definitions":{},"$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#","$id":"http://example.com/root.json","type":["object","null"],"required":["id","name","class"],"properties":{"id":{"$id":"#/properties/id","type":["integer","null"]},"name":{"$id":"#/properties/name","type":["string","null"]},"class":{"$id":"#/properties/class","type":["integer","null"]}}}
```

In this row 4 is corrupt records as the class column is of type Integer
So only this records has to be there in corrupt records, not the 5th row

Comment: Do you fix number of Columns? Are you decide schema of column dynamically or it is fix such as Class column will Int only?

Comment: can you bit more clear regarding schema of input data frame, means initially all will  be String and How you will decide its schema on the basis of column ?

Comment: We have a json schema from which we are extracting the column names and data types of it. 
Data Types of columns  Id : Integer, Name : String, Class : Integer

Comment: You can write simple UDF that will do type check for each row on the basis of your business rule, if it get corrupt data then it will return false other wise true. Run that udf with df and keep all value in new column. The column thats have false value that means there is something incorrect in that row.  If you can provide json file then I can try to write it. :)

Comment: JSON Schema: 

{"definitions":{},"$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#","$id":"http://example.com/root.json","type":["object","null"],"required":["id","name","class"],"properties":{"id":{"$id":"#/properties/id","type":["integer","null"]},"name":{"$id":"#/properties/name","type":["string","null"]},"class":{"$id":"#/properties/class","type":["integer","null"]}}}

Comment: I need to extract the datatype from this JSON schema for all the column and need to cast it with the current df. @Nikk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if value is `NOT NULL` before casting and `NULL` after casting

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when

df
  .withColumn("class_integer", $"class".cast("integer"))
  .withColumn(
    "class_corrupted", 
    when($"class".isNotNull and $"class_integer".isNull, $"class"))
```

Repeat for each column / cast you need.